# Using Gatsby + Material UI. Trying to make a navbar but with the buttons centered. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: material-ui, gatsby, css-in-js

I have googled for a few hours but I can't find anything.

Here is my code for my Navbar component:

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    toolbar: {
        textAlign: "center",
    },
    root: {
        background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 3,
        boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
        color: "white",
        height: 48,
        padding: "0 30px",
    },
}));

const NavBar = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static" color="secondary" elevation={0}>
                <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                    <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

As you can see, the important part is `<Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>`, as it refers to the css in js styling `textAlign: "center"`. My result is the button is on the left side, not the middle. Here is a picture to show:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQm4S.jpg)

Comment: I've updated your code and created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-y4tyd?file=/demo.js). I've used the `margin` property to center the element on the navbar.

Comment: the flex is also pretty handy in horizontal and vertical alignment of the items. I've also add the code snippet in commented form in the above sandbox. You can learn more about the flex system [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Its a pretty long guide if you're reading it first time and maybe use it as a reference to learn about the different flex properties over the time and whenever you need to implement some changes. Happy learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junaid has solved it, toolbar: should be:

```
toolbar: {
    dislay: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
```

It uses flexbox for easy layout. More here on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).